# What causes the difference in execution time between pickled transfomer and normal one?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib, dill

I have trained a dimensionality reduction model in scikit-learn. It applies PCA on term frequencies from a text.
After it has been trained, running the model takes around 1.7s. 
When I now pickle, using joblib or dill, and then unpickle the model in the same python shell, the execution time goes up to around 6s.

I profiled with %prun and this is the normal one

```
2430 function calls (2410 primitive calls) in 1.708 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    1.685    0.842    1.685    0.842 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.010    0.010    1.694    1.694 compressed.py:464(_mul_multivector)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method scipy.sparse._sparsetools.csr_matmat_pass2}
       54    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 numeric.py:424(asarray)
```

This is the pickled/unpickled one:

```
2428 function calls (2408 primitive calls) in 5.806 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    5.786    2.893    5.786    2.893 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.009    0.009    5.796    5.796 compressed.py:464(_mul_multivector)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method scipy.sparse._sparsetools.csr_matmat_pass2}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method scipy.sparse._sparsetools.csr_matmat_pass1}
        1    0.001    0.001    5.804    5.804 pipeline.py:752(transform)
```

So it seems the ravel function of numpy.ndarray is eating up a lot more time. Also when doing the dimensionality reduction on 1 or 10 samples makes no difference in execution time. What can cause this?

Update: I added an easy reproducible example below

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from time import time
from sklearn.externals import joblib
​

dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', shuffle=True, random_state=42)

tfidf_vectorizer_subl = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                   max_features=None,
                                   strip_accents = 'unicode',
                                   ngram_range =(1,2), 
                                   sublinear_tf=True
                                  )
tfidf_subl = tfidf_vectorizer_subl.fit_transform(dataset.data[:5000])

n_components = 1000
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components)
svd.fit(tfidf_subl)

t0 = time()
X_lsa = svd.transform(tfidf_subl)
print("done in %fs" % (time() - t0)) #done in 2.240295s

with open('test', 'wb') as file:
    joblib.dump(svd, file)  

with open('test' ,'rb') as f:
    svd_unpickled = joblib.load(f)

t0 = time()
X_lsa = svd_unpickled.transform(tfidf_subl)
print("done in %fs" % (time() - t0)) #done in 3.551007s WHY DOES THIS TAKE LONGER
```

- Python version: 3.5.3
- Numpy version: 1.14.3
- Scipy version: 1.1.0
- Sklearn version: 0.19.1

Comment: To be clear... you mean that running the same exact code (i.e. running the model, which has nothing to do with pickling) is slower after you've pickled and unpicked?   If so, I expect that it doesn't rebuild the same object (i.e. original was efficient, and the pickled model has made some speed sacrifices for the ability to be pickled).  The object isn't always what is pickled, sometimes it's reduced information that is used to reconstitute a similar object.

Comment: Did you pickle the data too?

Comment: Vivek,The data is not pickled. Both models get the exact same data.
@MikeMcKerns Indeed, that is exactly what i mean.

Comment: @Mishter_Jingles: I'd assume then if you compared the pre-pickled with the post-pickled model, you'd find that they are not identical objects (for example, something stored in python vs something referenced to C).

Comment: But AFAIK, pickle doesnt store method definition, only references. So that should not make a difference. Can you please make a reproducible example for it? Also show the numpy, scikit, python versions.

Comment: I will come with the code for a reproducible example on 14/5

Comment: I added a reproducible example

Comment: @MikeMcKerns How can I check that the objects are different, or if they are in c or python?

Comment: You can check if a particular object is a python object by (a) looking at the `__module__` attribute and then the `__file__` attribute of that module, and/or (b) looking at the name of the object itself (e.g. `builtin` means it's built-in C).  There are other methods too, but that's a start.  For checking if objects are different, the best place to start is `is` and `==`.